# Prevent click of Form 1 when Form 2 is open in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application where I have a Form 1 (Main Form). Inside this main form there is a button that opens up a different and smaller form (Form 2). I don't want to hide Form 1 when showing Form 2 but because of the size of Form 2, the user is able to click Form 1 hiding Form 2 with its size (not hidden like `Form2.hide();`) however this is something I don't want to do. I want to prohibit the user to click Form 1 if Form 2 is currently open. Is there any event or function I can use to do this? I have seen in it in other applications but I don't even know how to look for it.

Comment: `form2.ShowDialog();`

Comment: `ShowDialog()` prevents `Form1` from stealing focus.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) method as suggested in question's comments, you can disable the form itself if you want for example the user be able to switch between forms and view or copy some text.

> **Form.ShowDialog Method**: Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

Here is a definition:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window): A modal window creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it visible, with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users must interact with the modal window before they can return to the parent application. This avoids interrupting the workflow on the main window. Modal windows are sometimes called heavy windows or modal dialogs because they often display a dialog box.

If you don't want to use a modal form, you can initialize the `form2` instance like that:

```
form2.FormClosed += (_s, _e) => this.Enabled = true;
```

Thus now you can call:

```
this.Enabled = false;
form2.Show();
```

You can also check the [ShowInTaskBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar) property of the form2.

Be careful not to add the lambda event handler several times to the same instance: if form2 is just hidden on close, only one `FormClosed +=`  is needed, but is required for every instance of a form you want to manage this way.

If you need to disable only certain controls, use them instead of `this`:

```
private void SetControlsEnabled(bool state)
{
  myControl1.Enabled = state;
  myControl2.Enabled = state;
  myPanelHavingSomeControls = state; // this changes all inners too
  ...
}
```

```
form2.FormClosed += (_s, _e) => SetControlsEnabled(true);
```

```
SetControlsEnabled(false);
form2.Show();
```

Comment: From an UI perspective, using a proper modal form with `ShowDialog` is better than simulating it by disabling/enabling the parent form.

Answer (score -1):

This is the exact use case for a modal form, which disables the parent form and provides visual clues from the OS to tell the user of that relationship. Something along the lines of this will do:

```
//Code in the event handler that opens the child form
using (Form2 childForm = new Form2())
{
    //Put any initialization code here
    childForm.ShowDialog(this);
    //Any cleanup or using some return value from the form after it closed
}
```